# Trying to make bool out of parse.com async

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am using unity with parse.com and are very happy with it so far, but... Now I want to structure my files.

I am trying to create an login function like this:

When login button is clicked this method is run:

```
public void GoLogin(){

    string user = GameObject.Find("Login/Username").GetComponent<UIInput>().value;
    string pass = GameObject.Find("Login/Password").GetComponent<UIInput>().value;

    if(UserLogin(user,pass)){
        Debug.Log("Login is true");
        StartCoroutine(DoClose("loggedin"));
    } else {
        Debug.Log("login is false");
    }

}
```

I then try to make this parse call a boolean like this:

```
public bool UserLogin(string username, string pass){

    bool returnvalue = false;

    ParseUser.LogInAsync(username, pass).ContinueWith(t =>
                                                      {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log ("User do not exists");
            returnvalue = false;            
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ("User exists");
            returnvalue = true;
        }
    });

    return returnvalue;

}
```

This will make the boolean always false... How can i do this? Is it possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

`returnvalue` is always false because you are calling `LogInAsync`, which is an asynchronous method.  That means that execution of the task, and subsequent `ContinueWith` callback, will happen on a background thread.  This means that you hit `return returnvalue` while `LogInAsync` is actually running, before you actually get any result from the operation.

You can force a synchronous execution of this method by calling `Result` at the end of the task.  Also, instead of setting the variables inside your `ContinueWith` callback just return the value like any other function, this will make it available to `Result`.

```
public bool UserLogin(string username, string pass){

    return ParseUser.LogInAsync(username, pass).ContinueWith(t =>
                                                      {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log ("User do not exists");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ("User exists");
            return true;
        }

    }).Result;       

}
```

Be advised that making service calls or performing blocking operations on the UI thread is a bad idea, as it will cause your UI to lock up and result in a generally bad user experience.

Comment: this seems to lock and crash my Unity? Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by awaiting on the asynchronous operation. What is currently happening is that you're simply attaching a continuation to your async operation from your synchronous method. It returns immediatly, and you're left with the false boolean.

In order to do that, you'll need to mark your method `async` and make it return a `Task<bool>`. Note this is part of the fact that async bubbles all the way from buttom to top of the call stack.

```
public async Task<bool> LoginUserAsync(string username, string pass)
{
    bool isSuccess;
    try
    {
        await ParseUser.LogInAsync(username, pass);
        isSuccess = true;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         // Log
         isSuccess = false;
     }

     return isSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Itzchakow - When trying this I get some errors: "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type", "Unexpected symbol `LoginUserAsync' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" and "Class, struct, or interface method must have a return type". Can't figure out what is wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: @Mansa Where exactly are you getting this error? Could you paste the code into your question, or perhaps a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: The errors is referring to the first line in your example.

Comment: Unity 4.x uses Mono 2.6.

Comment: I see. You need Mono 3.2 to use `async-await` feature :\ My suggestion would be to use a synchronous version instead, if such exists of the `LogInAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a coroutine for this,

```
IEnumerator UserLogin(string username,string pass){
    Task task = ParseUser.LogInAsync(username, pass);
    while (!task.IsCompleted) yield return null;
    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
    {
        Debug.Log("login is false");   
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("User exists");
        // do your log in action here
        StartCoroutine(DoClose("loggedin"));
    }
}
```

[Check out parse documentation for more information](https://www.parse.com/docs/unity_guide#tasks-coroutines)